# css grid gap destroy layout

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm in trouble with css grid gap and my simple project. When I set gap on for example 1em this destroy my layout. Example:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.calculator {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2em;
    &__screen {
        flex-basis: 30%;
        background-color: royalblue;
    }
    &__body {
        flex-basis: 70%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%);
        gap: 1em;
        padding: 0.5em;

        .item {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="calculator__screen"></div>
            <div class="calculator__body">
                <div class="item">7</div>
                <div class="item">8</div>
                <div class="item">9</div>
                <div class="item">+</div>
                <div class="item">4</div>
                <div class="item">5</div>
                <div class="item">6</div>
                <div class="item">-</div>
                <div class="item">1</div>
                <div class="item">2</div>
                <div class="item">3</div>
                <div class="item">*</div>
                <div class="item">0</div>
                <div class="item">C</div>
                <div class="item">/</div>
                <div class="item">=</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is any method center items .calculator__body with css grid without overflow? I thought that  it's problem with box-sizing but i set it on border-box in my css reset . Earlier i had problem with auto fill all empty space vertically but discover that have to set grid-template-rows on 25%.

Comment: Please tag accordingly or use a parsed CSS instead of .scss. Then use `grid-template-rows:  repeat(4, 1fr)` instead of 25%. 25% means 25% of the parents element height and not the available space that exclude the gap

Comment: I tried do it earlier and there the items doesn't fill all free space in .calculator__body.  I'm sorry about dont paste css.

Comment: I had same problem. Don't mix unit between width, height and gap. If you have for example 4 columns, you have 3 gaps. if you put 1% for gap, your available width (or height) is 97%.  Put 1.333% gap, you have 96%. Each column 24%. Same way if you are using vw or vh... if you put gap in em, and column in %, you never which result you will have (in fact you can know, you render first, after you read the calculated values of the element you want, and modify them: but that's a mess).

Comment: @pierfarrugia that makles no sense. CSS has no issue with that. I mixing different units all the time since the past 6 years without issue.

Comment: @tacoshy, try you'll see, best

Comment: to add, yes you can mix unit in CSS. Now to calculate: 4 x 25% + 3 x 1em is more than 100% and CSS grid will wrap. When designing the layout we can't figure what would be the real size of 4x25% + 3x1em. You can calculate the real value of 1em but when it's rendered. So if you consider gap at 1.333% x 3 plus 4 x24%, you have 100%. At design time, we can imagine easily that 4x1.333% + 4x24% will be ok. It's a question mental representation and that works, not semantic on CSS on units